# UISearchController :how can I use obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation behaviour as true/false

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am using UISearchController and results controller will be the same.

```
 searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
   searchController?.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
```

// This will allow users won't able interact with tableview when search is active.

As I have told already if user search for something I will show the results in same view controller so when search starts "text did change" I want to disable this behavior. How can I achieve this.?

Comment: If search bar text length is greater then 0 then tableview's userintraction should be false